# Expanding DIV how to check when it has exceeded screen size

Tags: jquery, detect, off-screen

We have a DIV that is loaded with content based on user options in a form. The DIV can grow to large to be seen on screen as it is also a sticky element and follows the user on the screen.

How would we get the DIV to work out if some of itself is off screen and if so show a button that can then link to the full content.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a JS solution perhaps, this would work:

```
var topoffset = $div.offset().top;
var height = $div.height();
var pageHeight = $(window).height();

if ((topoffset + height) > pageHeight) {
  //the div is going outside the page
}
```

Comment: that should have worked. But I do not think it is calculating the topoffset correctly as the script is being triggered regardless. I tried it without the top offset and the script did not trigger anything

Answer (score 0):

if you can force the maximum width of your div, try this with CSS :

```
max-width: *YOUR_PAGE_WIDTH*px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via CSS,

```
overflow:auto;
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. Overflow must remail :hidden in order to facilitate the sticky element. I suppose a better way to put it would be can we detect if there is an overflow, and if so enact a script